# How to check if any errors occurred during ssh?

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

I'm writing a deployment script, and I need to rollback if any errors occurred.

Eg:

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh myapp '
    mkdir /some/dir
    # check if above command failed, and execute rollback script if needed
'
# or maybe do it from here?
```

Right now when I execute this script, if mkdir fails, it prints it on my screen and continues execution. I need to catch that error and do something about it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The exit status of `ssh` will be the exit status of the remote command. For instance

```
ssh myapp 'exit 42'
echo $?
```

should print 42 (`$?` is the exit status of the last command executed).

One option is to exit right away if the `mkdir` fails:

```
ssh myapp 'mkdir /some/dir || exit 42; do-more-stuff'
if [[ $? = 1 ]]; then
   echo "Remote mkdir failed"
fi
```

It is probably better to try to handle any remote failures in your script, if possible.

Answer (score 6):

If you really need to catch the *error message* you can try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
result=`ssh myapp 'mkdir /some/dir' 2>&1`
if [[ -n $result ]]; then
    echo "the following error occurred: $result"
fi
```

By this you redirect the standard error output to the standard output and save the output of the ssh command to `$result`. If you just need the error code / exit status, see [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/457289/138199).